# Apply calculations based on certain conditions in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, with-statement

I have the following data frame:

```
Source  mean1   SD  median  range_min   range_max   IQR_25  IQR_75  
1       1.5     0.2 3       NA          NA          NA      NA      
2       NA      NA  2       1           5           1.5     4       
3       NA      NA  4       2           7           NA      NA
```

I want to add `mean2` and `FLAG` columns into the data frame based on certain conditions. The conditions are the following:

1) If `mean1` and `sd` are present then copy the same value into the `mean2` column and give it `FLAG ==1`

2) If `mean1` and `sd` are `NA` but `median:IQR_75` are present then put value equal 20 for `mean2` and give it a `FLAG==2`. Note: the value 20 is arbitrary. I will be putting an equation instead but this is to make it easy for the question here.

3) If if `mean1` and `sd` are `NA` but `median, RANGE_min, RANGE_max` are present then then put value equal 30 for `mean2` and give it a `FLAG==3`.

The result should look like the following:

```
Source  mean1   SD  median  range_min   range_max   IQR_25  IQR_75  mean2   FLAG
1       1.5     0.2 3       NA          NA          NA      NA      1.5     1
2       NA      NA  2       1           5           1.5     4       20      2
3       NA      NA  4       2           7           NA      NA      30      3
```

I have tried the following but didn't have much luck in using it:

```
df$mean2 <- with(df, (is.na(mean1)==F&(is.na(SD)==F))*mean1+ (is.na(mean1)==T & is.na(SD)==T & is.na(median)==F &
                        is.na(range_min)==F & is.na(range_max)==F & is.na(IQR_25)==F &
                        is.na(IQR_75)==F)*20)
```

I would ask your help in acheving my goal so I can apply it on my big data set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `data.table` package you could do it as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!is.na(mean1) & !is.na(SD), `:=` (mean2 = mean1, Flag = 1)
          ][is.na(mean1) & is.na(SD) & complete.cases(median,range_min,range_max,IQR_25,IQR_75),
            `:=` (mean2 = 20, Flag = 2)
            ][is.na(mean1) & is.na(SD) & complete.cases(median,range_min,range_max) & is.na(IQR_25) & is.na(IQR_75),
              `:=` (mean2 = 30, Flag = 3)]
```

this gives:

```
> df
   Source mean1  SD median range_min range_max IQR_25 IQR_75 mean2 Flag
1:      1   1.5 0.2      3        NA        NA     NA     NA   1.5    1
2:      2    NA  NA      2         1         5    1.5      4  20.0    2
3:      3    NA  NA      4         2         7     NA     NA  30.0    3
```

Alternatively, you can create indexes for your several conditions beforehand. This will give much cleaner `data.table` syntax:

```
indx1 <- complete.cases(df[c("mean1", "SD")])
indx2 <- complete.cases(df[c("median","range_min","range_max","IQR_25","IQR_75")])
indx3 <- !complete.cases(df[c("IQR_25","IQR_75")]) & complete.cases(df[c("median","range_min","range_max")])

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[indx1, `:=` (mean2 = mean1, Flag = 1)
          ][!indx1 & indx2, `:=` (mean2 = 20, Flag = 2)
            ][!indx1 & indx3, `:=` (mean2 = 30, Flag = 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it gave the following error: `Error in complete.cases(median, RANGEpH_MIN, RANGEpH_MAX, IQRpH_25, IQRpH_75) : 
  invalid 'type' (closure) of argument`

Comment: Did you specify the names correctly? Did you load `data.table`? It works on the example dataset you provided.

Comment: Sorry. I missed up with one name. It is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can create a couple of logical indexes based on the NA elements in the specified columns.  The 'indx' gives TRUE if both 'mean1' and 'SD' are not NA, 'indx2' will be TRUE if there are no NA values in a row for 'median:IQR_75' column as we are taking the `rowSums` of the NA elements.  Similarly, 'indx3' gives TRUE for non-NA elements for columns 'median:range_max'.

```
 indx <- rowSums(!is.na(df1[c('mean1', 'SD')]))==2
 indx2 <- !rowSums(is.na(df1[4:ncol(df1)]))
 indx3 <- !rowSums(is.na(df1[4:6]))
```

Now we can create a numeric index by arithmetic operations to create a unique index ('indx4') which can be used to populate the values 1.5, 30, 20 or 1:3.

```
 indx4 <- as.numeric(factor(1+2*indx+4*indx2+8*indx3))
  c(1.5, 30, 20)[indx4]
 #[1]  1.5 20.0 30.0
 c(1,3,2)[indx4]
 #[1] 1 2 3
```

Or we use a nested `ifelse`

```
 df1$mean2 <- ifelse(indx, 1.5, ifelse(indx2, 20, ifelse(indx3, 30, NA)))
 df1$mean2
 #[1]  1.5 20.0 30.0

 df1$FLAG <- ifelse(indx, 1, ifelse(indx2, 2, ifelse(indx3, 3, NA)))
 df1$FLAG
 # [1] 1 2 3

df1
#   Source mean1  SD median range_min range_max IQR_25 IQR_75 mean2 FLAG
#1      1   1.5 0.2      3        NA        NA     NA     NA   1.5    1
#2      2    NA  NA      2         1         5    1.5      4  20.0    2
#3      3    NA  NA      4         2         7     NA     NA  30.0    3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Source = 1:3, mean1 = c(1.5, NA, NA), SD = c(0.2, 
 NA, NA), median = c(3L, 2L, 4L), range_min = c(NA, 1L, 2L),
 range_max = c(NA, 
 5L, 7L), IQR_25 = c(NA, 1.5, NA), IQR_75 = c(NA, 4L, NA)),
 .Names = c("Source", 
 "mean1", "SD", "median", "range_min", "range_max", "IQR_25", 
 "IQR_75"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df$mean2 = NA
df$FLAG = NA

ind1 = complete.cases(df[, c("mean1", "SD")])
ind2 = complete.cases(df[, c("median", "range_min", "range_max", "IQR_25", "IQR_75")])
ind3 = complete.cases(df[, c("median", "range_min", "range_max")])

df$mean2[ind1] = df$mean1[ind1]
df$mean2[!ind1 & ind2] = 20 
df$mean2[!ind1 & !ind2 & ind3] = 30

df$FLAG[ind1] = 1
df$FLAG[!ind1 & ind2] = 2 
df$FLAG[!ind1 & !ind2 & ind3] = 3
```